# Email sent to a document library: "Created By" is sometimes set to "System Account"

Tags: 2007, workflow, document-library, email

On SharePoint 2007, I enabled a document library to receive emails. I then use a workflow to send a response to the user who sent the message. The workflow uses the field "Created By" whose value is usually the sender.

About 40% of the time, however, "Created By" is set to "System Account". I was not able to understand why this happens. There does not seem to be any difference between the users for whom it works and those for whom it doesn't. For example, I can find them in the people picker using their email addresses.

Do you guys have any idea why this happens?
I am also interested in alternative solutions to send an email back to the sender.

Comment: Is that user a Farm Account???

Comment: No, none of them is a farm account.

Comment: Can u check web application user policy under>>> Security>>users. Here if u configure an account, u can also mention it as a system account.. check whether some unique id is present there.

Comment: hi.., did u get the solution?

Answer (score 2):

It usually happens when the alert is triggered by the **Farm Account**. Can you try it with another normal account.

---

In the above comment, I had mentioned that check in web app policy... there u can find **NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE** click it and check whether the option account operates as system is checked..

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it did not work.